# Automatically copy row based on value in Column K

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a sheet of pending purchase orders on the "pending" sheet. Once an order is received, I enter the date it was received. After I enter the date I would like for the entire row to be moved over to the "received" sheet. Can anyone help? I need to make this log more efficient at work.

The information is on b7:k50. The column that I would put the date in is "k".

Comment: Try `worksheet_change`

Comment: downvoted, because, while we can help, we can't do much if you don't already show us what you have tried to do on your own. this is not a "write code for me, please" website. it's a website to help with specific programming problems. Please post any code you have tried to get your solution and where you are stuck, and we'd be happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understand your data setup, but here is a solution:

When we add a date to column `K` (`K2:K50`), it will move the row to the "CompletedOrders" worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
'If we change a value in Range("K2:K50")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K50")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Copy Range A:K on the Target Row
    Range("A" & Target.Row & ":" & "K" & Target.Row)).Copy
    'Paste it to the CompletedOrders Sheet, column A (after the last row)
    Sheets("CompletedOrders").Range("A" & Sheets("CompletedOrders").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial
    'Delete the row we just copied from the Pending Orders Sheet
    Target.EntireRow.Delete (xlShiftUp)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

PendingOrders sheet before hitting enter:

[image: Completed1]

CompletedOrders sheet:

[image: Completed2]